# MySQL - Conditional SELECT to output separate columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, conditional-statements

I am trying to get around an apparently simple problem in MySQL: I have a table composed by 3 fields and I would like to form a query that returns a field selected as DISTINCT and two more columns which return a COUNT of the remaining two fields when a specific condition is met.

To illustrate (columns named *first*, *second* and *third* left to right):

```
| VzokAAD | aaa | 0 |
| VziAAAT | bbb | 0 |
| VziAAAT | ccc | 1 |
| VziAAAT | ddd | 0 |
| W0cZAAT | eee | 1 |
| VziNAAT | fff | 1 |
| VzpqAAD | ggg | 1 |
| VzpqAAD | hhh | 1 |
```

My current query is structured as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(first) AS field_one, COUNT(second) 
FROM table WHERE third = 0 GROUP BY field_one;
```

So the above query will return:

```
 | VzokAAD | 1 |
 | VziAAAT | 2 |
```

I can change the query to something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(first) AS field_one, COUNT(second) 
FROM table WHERE third = 1 GROUP BY field_one;
```

And it will return:

```
 | VzpqAAD | 2 |
 | VziNAAT | 1 |
 | W0cZAAT | 1 |
 | VziAAAT | 1 |
```

How do I get both queries combined together so that, I get the first column GROUPED and DISTINCT and two additional columns with the COUNT of third =1 and third =0 respectively.

Basically something like this (wrong of course):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(first) AS field_one, COUNT(second WHERE third = 1) 
AS alpha, COUNT(second WHERE third = 0) AS beta FROM table GROUP BY field_one;
```

I tried to use CASE and IF control flow functions however I only managed to get the results defined in a single column.

Thanks to anyone willing to lend a hand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use this query :

```
 select first , SUM(IF(third=0,1,0)) as Col_zero, SUM(IF(third=1,1,0)) as Col_one
 from table
 group by first;
```

Comment: Absolutely fantastic - worked right away just as I wanted it! Thanks Sugar Joon!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` in following:

```
SELECT first AS field_one, 
       COUNT(second) 
FROM table 
WHERE third = 0 
GROUP BY field_one;
UNION
SELECT first AS field_one, 
       COUNT(second) 
FROM table 
WHERE third = 1 
GROUP BY field_one;
```

---

Also how about `IN`?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(first) AS field_one, 
       COUNT(second) 
FROM table 
WHERE third IN(0, 1) 
GROUP BY field_one;
```

Comment: DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: The problem with UNION is that it merged all the output into one column :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT 
      first AS field_one, 
      (CASE WHEN third =0 THEN COUNT(second) END)AS count1, 
      (CASE WHEN third=1 THEN COUNT(second) END)AS count2
FROM my_table
WHERE third IN('0','1')
GROUP BY field_one
```

Comment: why Distinct is required here?

Comment: This was an interesting alternative however I found that it would only count one of the two output columns (count1 or count2) leaving the other column as NULL. I am not completely sure of the reason but if anybody knows it would be a good tip to learn.